# ReactJS material-ui input validation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[Input Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0ayd.png)

At the moment my validation checks whether length of uniquecode is 14 or not.

Format of unique code must be in. (4-6-4)
Example XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX

How can I have my input field validate whether format is correct or not using (4-6-4)

```html
    //{Handles inputfields}
    const uniquecodeChange = (e) => {
        // console.log("Input uniquecode", e.target.value);
        if (uniquecodereg.length < 1) {
            Setvalidateform(false)
            console.log('checking error')
        } else if (uniquecodereg.length > 14) {
            Setvalidateform(true)
            console.log('checking true')
        }

        setUniqueCodeReg(e.target.value)
    }





 <WhiteTextField
   variant="outlined"
   placeholder={"XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX"}
   disabled={registerStatus === 'success'}
   onChange={uniquecodeChange}
  type="text"
  name="code"
  inputProps={{ maxLength: 16 }}
  required={true}
  value={uniquecodereg}
  fullWidth
 />
```

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, you can mark it as the accepted answer for this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use regex to test the input... I was not sure what your requirement is in terms of upper, lower, a-z, 0-9 or what, so I just included them all.

https://regex101.com/r/i42D74/3

Note my regex is a bit rusty, anybody feel free to optimize if possible.

Optimized based on Roman's comment.

```js
var patt = new RegExp("XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX");
var res = /[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}/.test(patt); 

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You can remove some of the characters: `/[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}/`

Comment: Thanks! I’ll update the answer. Didn’t know you could do it that way.

Comment: Thank you for help, new to react js :)

Comment: No problem. An important thing to note is that regex isn’t a react thing per day, but rather a feature that is built in to the JavaScript language (with the .test function).